# Raster analysis , Proximity (raster distance)

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, distance

This is my first message here. I am trying to create a proximity map with the Raster analysis tool. My problem is that I only get two options for distance units , pixels coordinates and georeferenced coordinates while I want to get them in meters.

I also used the grass tool , r.grow.distance that provides in advanced parameters the option "Output distances in meters instead of map units" If i check this option i get the following error ERROR: Raster map or group not found.

Does any of you know any workaround for this?

I am using QGiS 3.8.1 with GRASS 7.6.1

Answer (score 2):

If you raster's projection unit is meter, then the output unit of the proximity raster will be meters if you specify georeferenced units. In case your raster's projection unit is not meter (*e.g.* is degree because it is on WGS84), you'll want to reproject your raster to another coordinate system (such as UTM, for example).